# Range Name Clears After Saving File

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a problem regarding excel cell range. So I have an excel file containing cell ranges but when I save it and reopened the same file some cell ranges were missing. I have tried "save as" but still same results. I have also done researching but still no luck. Hope someone helps me. Thank you in advanced. I'm losing time figuring it out. Any help would be really appreciated!

Is there a VBA code or macro equivalent for my problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.

Comment: I'm very sorry for that. But excel has macros and uses VBA, and maybe using those can be the solution. So I think my question is valid.But I'm very sorry if its not. And maybe someone knows how. Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you can share the file, preferably a before and after version?

Comment: Would want to, but hadn't a chance to savea copy on my phone. I'm on phone right now. Don't have the access to my office desktop right now. So I guess I'll just explain it further. Here is the scenario: created cell name range in file.xlsx, successfully saved it, viewed the name manager and all are listed ex: title, box, circle, square, format. Closes the file, open it again then open name manager then some defined cell range were missing, left were title, box. Sorry I'm too noob for this.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, what I suggest you try is to get into the VBA and set a 'stop' in the open and close event handlers.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Stop
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Stop
End Sub
```

These should be placed in the ThisWorkbook class in the VBIDE.

If these handlers already exist then just put the Stop at the first line in the handler code.

Then just as you open and just as you close you will be able to see if the data exists at those times.

That may give you a chance to see if there's any VBA clearing out your data ranges.

Comment: Sir/Ma'am, Thank you very much for that. Really appreciated, Will surely try that first thing when I got to my workplace. That would make me progress. I'm really new to excel VBA stuffs, thanks for  the respone. Just curious, if possibly there's a VBA clearing my cell ranges, is deleting that VBA which causes that fault would be fine? Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. You can remove the offending code in the even handlers and excel would continue as normal. However, if it has a deletion of cells, there might actually be a reason since it is intentionally there in the first place. Just remember to remove the Stops when you are finished. By the way, pressing Shift + F2 when opening Excel will disable macros and allow you to put in your debug code.